# Django can not migrate model after create function for rename file

Tags: python, django, django-models

I create rename function for rename file in model with this code.

```
def path_and_rename(path):
    def path_and_rename_func(instance, filename):
        upload_to = path
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        # get filename
        if instance.pk:
            filename = '{}.{}'.format(instance.pk, ext)
        else:
            # set filename as random string
            filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
        # return the whole path to the file
        return os.path.join(upload_to, filename)
    return path_and_rename_func
```

I use the function like this.

```
image=models.ImageField(upload_to=path_and_rename("test_image"))
video=models.FileField(upload_to=path_and_rename("test_file"),blank=True, null=True)
```

when I use command for migration `python manage.py makemigrations`

It show error like this.

```
ValueError: Could not find function path_and_rename_func in Test.models.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Look at your `return` statement, you are just returning the function reference.

Comment: You can not work with such wrapped functions, since there is no immediate reference to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not work with such wrapped functions, since that means that the resulting function has no qualified name.

You can however define two helper functions and use these, for example with:

```
def path_and_rename_func(instance, filename, path):
    upload_to = path
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    # get filename
    if instance.pk:
        filename = '{}.{}'.format(instance.pk, ext)
    else:
        # set filename as random string
        filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
    # return the whole path to the file
    return os.path.join(upload_to, filename)

def path_and_rename_test_image(instance, filename):
    return path_and_rename(instance, filename, 'test_image')

def path_and_rename_test_file(instance, filename):
    return path_and_rename(instance, filename, 'test_file')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=path_and_rename_test_image)
    video = models.FileField(
        upload_to=path_and_rename_test_file,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```